# Referencing a parent form from a child form

Tags: c#

i have a MainForm where i open another form, now i have class that provides me with some function that i wrote one function gets a reference of the main form and a reference of the opened form and other parameter i call the function in the opened form and to refer to the MainForm i use this.Parent but i get error "object reference not set on an instance of an opject".

*ClientSide is my MainForm
*LogIn is the form that i open in the mainform and where i call the method RunListener

```
class ServicesProvider
{
 public static void RunListener(ClientSide MainForm,LogIn LogForm,System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Client)
    {
     //Doing my things with the parameters
    }
}
```

this code is in the LogIn form

```
private void BtLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Thread Listener = new Thread(delegate()
                 {
                   ServicesProvider.RunListener((ClientSide)this.Parent,this,tcpClient);
                 });
                Listener.Start();
    }
```

the problem is that whenever i debug i get the error i told you and i found that the code "(ClinetSide)this.parent" refer to null.
i need to refer to the main form in order to work on it and change some values.

Comment: Are you showing the child form like this:? `child.Show(parent);` or `child.ShowDialog(parent);`

Comment: LogIn LogForm = new LogIn();
            LogForm.ShowDialog();
like this

Comment: thax @PeterRitchie you inspired me, i changed the LogIn form constructor and let it get a ClientSide parameter.
LogIn LogForm=new LogIn(this);
LogForm.showDialog();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Form1=Parent

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace childform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 tempDialog = new Form2(this);
            tempDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void msgme()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Parent Function Called");
        }

    }
}
```

and Form2=Child

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace childform
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 m_parent;

        public Form2(Form1 frm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_parent = frm1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_parent.msgme();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A form doesn't know about a "parent" by default, you must tell it.  For example:

```
LogForm.ShowDialog(parentForm);
```